# How can I download Docs to Iphone using GoogleDocAPI

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Is it possible to download the documents from my gmail account to documents folder for iphone app. Actually i used Google Doc API and get Feed by using

```
-(GDataServiceGoogleDocs *)getdocservice
{
    static GDataServiceGoogleDocs *docs = nil;
    if(!docs)
    {
        docs = [[GDataServiceGoogleDocs alloc]init];
        [docs setShouldCacheResponseData:YES];
        [docs setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
        [docs setIsServiceRetryEnabled:YES];
        [docs setUserCredentialsWithUsername:@"gmailaccount@gmail.com" password:@"password"];
    }
    return docs;
}

//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
#pragma mark docService
docsService = [self getdocservice];

NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleDocs docsFeedURL];
GDataQueryDocs *queryDocs = [GDataQueryDocs documentQueryWithFeedURL:feedURL];
[queryDocs setMaxResults:1000];
[queryDocs setShouldShowFolders:YES];
ticket = [docsService fetchFeedWithQuery:queryDocs delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(docsFetchTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];


// call back
-(void)docsFetchTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedDocList *)feed error:(NSError *)error
{
    GDataFeedDocList *mDocListFeed = feed;
    int numDocs = [[feed entries] count];
    NSLog(@"NumDocs :%d\n Feed :%@",numDocs,mDocListFeed);

    for (int i=0; i<numDocs; i++) {
        GDataEntryDocBase *docEntry = [mDocListFeed entryAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"\n@@@@@@@@@@@@ DocTitle :%@\n\n",[[docEntry content] sourceURL] );
    }
}
```

it is displaying all the documents from my account .
But i am not getting how to download those documents into my app document folder. If any one have idea please help me.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I am not proficient in Objective-C)

Each entries of the GDataFeedDocList should contain a link which points to the actual file's data. The link is contained in its "Content" attribute. In your code it seems that you have that URL (sourceURL) you need to download the content using an authenticated request to taht URL.

You should also now use the newer Drive API instead of the DocumentList API using the newer Objective-C client library:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/